# Java POJO not showing null fields in MongoDB

Tags: java, android, json, mongodb, pojo

I am new in android and I need to ask a question. I have a `mongodb database` where I `POST` and `Get` records. I also have a `pojo` in my app through which I send the whole object to the database but it is not showing null fields. I want to show the data like this

```
{  
 "name" : "xyz",
 "logd" : null  
}
```

but it is not showing the null fields at all. I already tried the `jackson's @JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS` but no use. Does anyone have a solution for this.
Thanks.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: Null and not existant are handled the same way, You may also try saving the null value like "logd" : "" as empty string, it may work

Comment: I already done this but it is showing String datatype in mongodb but i want Null datatype in mongo.

Comment: "upvoted"..., the question specified desired behavior and stated the problem.@Selvin

Answer (score 0):

Though you are specifying that using Jackson library, you can't configure mongodb to store the property if there its null.

Comment: is there any other solution for this??

Comment: none that i know of. how about just putting "null" as text? and your code handles it.

Comment: I don't want string datatype in mongo. Need Null type.